# Shared subservient object

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a template class `Foo` that has a method, `barMethod`, that requires a `Bar` object.  I could have each individual `Foo` object create `Bar` objects as needed, but I don't want to do that because it will be slow, and  there is a good chance that different `Foo` objects could use the same `Bar` object.

Given that, I would like to have a `BarManager` object that has the existing set of `Bar` objects.  The `Foo` objects could then ask it for `Bar` objects, and if an appropriate one already exists, the manager would simply return it.  If it doesn't the manager would create a new one and return it.

It seems to me that there are two problems with implementing the "manager" approach.

1. The manager would have to be a global variable, which I would prefer not to do.
2. `BarManager` and `Bar` are both template classes, so even if I were to make the manager a global variable/object, I'm not sure how that would work.  I guess I could make the global variable a void * and cast it whenever it is de-referenced to the appropriate templated class, but that seems really ugly.

There has to be a way to do this that isn't so ugly (perhaps using an `auto` pointer?).  What is it?

EDIT: This software is part of a library that I (and perhaps others) will use later, which is why the classes are templated and the template type is not known *a priori*.  Also, I want to keep things as simple as possible for the user of `Foo`, so I do not want the caller to have to do anything with `BarManager` or `Bar` (e.g. instantiating `BarManager` and giving the reference to each `Foo`).

Comment: Would the type of `BarManager` and `Bar` requested by the `Foo` objects be consistent? Or does `Foo` need a `BarManager` that is unspecified at construction?

Comment: @JonathanMee They are all templated consistently- i.e. `Foo<T>` would use `BarManager<T>` and `Bar<T>`.

Comment: What exactly speaks against injection of the BarManager? From an organic point of view, I see it somewhat like a librarian. He manages the books and you can ask him to give you access to one of the books based on criteria you give him. However, there can be several librarians in the world (thus not a global variable or singleton), so you need to have the address to the library (injected as a pointer to BarManager).

Comment: @Aziuth I don't know what you mean by "injection of the BarManager".  And it seems like having multiple BarManagers with a singleton "library" still has the same problem- how do I do the templated library?

Comment: What I meant was that you simple pass down ("inject") a pointer or reference of BarManager to any place where Foo needs it. Like your main creating an instance of BarManager and the constructor of Foo gets a pointer to it. Simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you:

1. Know concrete type of `BarManager` in compile time.
2. Don't want any user of Foo knowing about this internal mechanism.

Then you can have all `Foo` classes holds this `BarManager` as a `static` (definitely not a global var)

```
template <typename T>
class Bar{};

template <typename T>
class BarManager;

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
    static BarManager<T>& GetBarManager()
    {
        static BarManager<T> managerInstance;
        return managerInstance;
    }

public:
    void barMethod()
    {
        auto& bar = GetBarManager().GetBarInstance();

        // Do something with `bar`
    }
};

template <typename T>
class BarManager
{
public:
    Bar<T>& GetBarInstance()
    {
        // Replace with cacher implementation:
        static Bar<T> dud;
        return dud; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.barMethod();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clever use of static!  I like it.

Comment: One question- could I do this without the base class and the inheritance?  If the inheritance is to hide BarManager I don't need to go that far, I just didn't want the user to have to instantiate BarManager themself and pass in the reference to Foo.

Comment: Answer is a direct yes and I'll edit accordingly. Just wasn't sure how far you wanted to go for hiding this detail.

Comment: @JimClay The problem with those function scope static singletons is that you cannot pass parameters to its constructor. Also, there is en extra atomic variable check when accessing it, which may be extremely cheap, but it is not free. Thirdly, you don't know exactly when it is going to destroy.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin The first problem is solved easily by having it stored as a static member of the class itself (`unique_ptr` could be an option) and having it initialized explicitly, parameters passed freely, at a certain early enough point in the pipeline. If the second problem is an issue for the OP then he should have specified this pretty extreme performance consideration.

Comment: I also got a downvote for another perfectly viable solution :/ Though in the end I do like yours better with the `static BarManager` so I've graced it with an upvote. It's just really easy to use. Though depending upon the weight of `Bar` (or even worse the potential of multiple `Bar`s that I assumed) the `static` may not be the most ideal solution? Either way this really clever +1

Comment: @JimClay Perhaps it would be wise to edit the question to add that you didn't want the user of `Foo` to have to instantiate BarManager themself/pass in the reference? Otherwise people will keep asking themselves why not pass it...

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives on how to refer to `BarManager`:

1. Have it as a global object / global pointer to a local object in `main()` / singleton / monostate. The advantage is easy access to it.
2. Pass a pointer/reference to an instance of `BarManager` explicitly. The advantage is that you can have many `BarManager` objects. The disadvantage is having to pass the extra parameter to calls, especially if the call chains are deep and/or having to store a reference/pointer to it as a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd need whatever was responsible for constructing `Foo`s to first have constructed all `BarManager`s and then pass them into the `Foo` on construction. Since I don't really know the specifics I'll have to leave that to you, but given a simple: `template<typename T> struct Bar { using value_type = T; const T _val; };` your `BarManager` skeleton could look like this:

```
template<typename T>
class BarManager {
    vector<shared_ptr<Bar<T>>> _bars;
public:
    using value_type = T;
    size_t size() { size(_bars); }
    shared_ptr<Bar<T>>& get_bar(const T target) {
        const auto it = find_if(begin(_bars), end(_bars), [&](const shared_ptr<Bar<T>>& i) { return i->_val == target; });

        if(it == end(_bars)) {
            _bars.push_back(make_shared<Bar<T>>(target));
            return _bars.back();
        } else {
            return *it;
        }
    }
};
```

From there your `Foo` can look like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    shared_ptr<BarManager<T>> _my_manager;
    shared_ptr<Bar<T>> _my_bar;
public:
    using value_type = T;
    Foo(shared_ptr<BarManager<T>>& my_manager) : _my_manager(my_manager) {}
    void request_bar(const T& target) { _my_bar = _my_manager->get_bar(target); }
};
```

Comment: I agree that that is workable, but I would prefer a solution where the details are completely hidden from the user of Foo.  Is there such a solution?

Comment: If you structure object lifetimes hierarchically (which you should), there won't be any need for `shared_ptr`. I would say that most of the time `shared_ptr` leads to poor designs.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin While your suggestion is good, after consideration, I realized that the hierarchical solution leaves `Bar`s and `BarManager`s around after the destruction of `Foo` object, which I didn't like. Knowing a little more about the usage may help me to decide how this could be handled... Though perhaps you have some suggestions of how we could ensure `Bar` and `BarManager` cleanup while structuring according to "object lifetime hierarchy"?

Comment: @JimClay Sadly your class `Foo` is a template class, thus anything pertaining to `T` will have to be exposed in the header :(